# JQuery smooth scroll functionality not working on moving to angularjs 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I coded a html web page and had applied jquery smooth scroll functionality. Its working fine here but after upgrading AngularJS 2 everything is working fine except smooth scroll.

My scrolling JavaScript is like this

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]), button[onclick="location.href=#"]').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also tried this function to bind inside $(document).ready({}) but with no success.

I am working on visual studio with ASP.Net MVC framework.

Comment: share your html code

Comment: The snippet looks good. Probably the problem is not this part ... maybe its the links itself or something else interfering